# Unable to sort selected cells within the Table in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, sorting

I created a Table in Excel 2013 but I want to sort only selected cells. The table range is A1:I200 but I only want to sort A150:I200. I tried selecting the cells, right click, sort, it sorted the whole table. Is there a solution on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following macro works that out. You first Unlist the Table, then Sort the selected Range, and then Create the ListObject again. You should adapt the Sub to fine tune the details as needed.

```
Sub part_sort()
    Dim rng_sel As Range, rng_all As Range
    Dim lo_table As ListObject, lo_name As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng_sel = Selection
    Set lo_table = rng_sel.ListObject
    lo_name = lo_table.Name
    Set rng_all = lo_table.Range
    Debug.Print rng_all.Address
    lo_table.Unlist

    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng_sel.Columns(1), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rng_sel
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Set lo_table = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng_all, , xlYes)
    lo_table.Name = lo_name
End Sub
```

PS: This question is probably better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I copied and pasted the codes and works perfectly the way I want it. I appreciate the help.